# How to link buttons in toolbar in Sencha touch?

Tags: button, sencha-touch, extjs

I have multiple buttons loading up in the button toolbar I need those buttons to go to different links. However, I have not been able to figure it out. Below is what I tried to do but it does not work.

```
        //Below are three buttons that need to go to three different links 
    var buttonsGroup1 = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'MESSAGES',
    handler: tapHandler
    });

    var buttonsGroup2 = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'HOLDS',
    handler: tap2Handler
    });

    var buttonsGroup3 = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'FINANCIALS',
    handler: tapHandler
    });

    //Click on the button and it goes to these links 
    var tapHandler = function (btn, evt) {
        window.location = 'index.html';
    };

    var tap2Handler = function (btn, evt) {
        window.location = 'redirect.php';
    };

    //Combine all the variables above and some other stuff and then add it to docked items very object oriented =)
    var dockedItems = [
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        title: 'Student Portal',
        ui: 'light',
        dock: 'top',
        items: buttonsSpecTop,
        defaults: { handler: tapHandler }
    },  
    {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: 'dark',
        items: [buttonsGroup1, buttonsGroup2, buttonsGroup3], //This is where I load up all the buttons 
        dock: 'bottom',
        layout:{
        pack: 'center'
        },
        defaults: [handler: tapHandler, handler: tap2Handler] //This is the handler for the links

    }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each button config, add one extra config param say actionUrl this way:

```
{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    actionUrl : 'http://www.google.com',
    title: 'Student Portal',
    ui: 'light',
    dock: 'top',
    items: buttonsSpecTop,
    defaults: { handler: tapHandler }
}
```

Now, for tapHandler function, the first parameter is the button instance. So, you can get the url this way:

```
function tapHandler(btn){
   console.log(btn);
   window.open(btn.actionUrl);
}
```

And you cannot put things in javascript this way inside an array:

```
defaults: [handler: tapHandler, handler: tap2Handler]
```

You have to use an object for that, similar to the first one:

```
defaults: { handler: tapHandler }
```

And, you cannot put multiple parameter of same name within a single object, only one "**handler**" will go there. And for **defaults**, only one handler will be applied to all the items. So, if you want individual handlers for individual buttons, use handler listener to each of the button.

Comment: how would I use the handler listener to each of the button

Comment: I can see, you have already attached handler (tapHandler and tapHandler2) to each individual button. So, just remove the default config. It will work.