# Make docked item a link - Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch

I have two docked items in my `Ext.Panel` in my Sencha Touch app. I want them to be links that take the user to a URL and away from the app. These are the items:

```
{
                    iconCls: 'facebook',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    iconMask: false,
                    icon: '../../Content/resources/css/facebook.png?1'
                },
                {
                    iconCls: 'twitter2',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    iconMask: false,
                    icon: '../../Content/resources/css/twitter.png',
                }
```

How would I make them links and specify the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a handler to the buttons and the handler will do a Javascript page redirect

Ex. `window.location = http://...`

Comment: How would I setup the handler?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473719/how-to-link-buttons-in-toolbar-in-sencha-touch

Answer (score 0):

```
            {
                iconCls: 'facebook',
                ui: 'plain',
                iconMask: false,
                icon: '../../Content/resources/css/facebook.png?1',
                getElConfig  : function(){ return {tag: 'a', id: this.id }; }
            },
            {
                iconCls: 'twitter2',
                ui: 'plain',
                iconMask: false,
                icon: '../../Content/resources/css/twitter.png',
                getElConfig  : function(){ return {tag: 'a', id: this.id }; }
            }
```